# Primefaces - binding and schedule

Tags: binding, jsf-2, primefaces, schedule

I want to change the attribute `rightHeaderTemplate` of a schedule in a `ManagedBean`. So I want to bind my schedule but I don't know the type of the object to use in the `ManagedBean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the java object of `schedule` , use this [Class Schedule](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.2/org/primefaces/component/schedule/Schedule.html)

use [setRightHeaderTemplate](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.2/org/primefaces/component/schedule/Schedule.html#setRightHeaderTemplate%28java.lang.String%29)

---

BUT,

INMO , there is no need to bind to object

just use this attribute of the `<p:schedule` component like this

```
<p:schedule rightHeaderTemplate="#{myBean.myHeaderTemplate}"></p:schedule>
```

**I think You misunderstood the meaning of the headers of the schedule component**

> Header controls of Schedule can be customized based on templates, valid values of template options
>   are;
>
> • title: Text of current month/week/day information
>
> • prev: Button to move calendar back one month/week/day.
>
> • next: Button to move calendar forward one month/week/day.
>
> • prevYear: Button to move calendar back one year
>
> • nextYear: Button to move calendar forward one year
>
> • today: Button to move calendar to current month/week/day.
>
> • viewName: Button to change the view type based on the view type.
>
> These controls can be placed at three locations on header which are defined with
>
> leftHeaderTemplate, rightHeaderTemplate and centerTemplate attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

If i write "schedule.setRightHeaderTemplate("test");" the right header is empty. 
But il i write "schedule.setRightHeaderTemplate("title");" i have August 2012.

It's possible to personalize the right header ?

Comment: effectively, but how to custom the right header ? It works when the value is "title" or "month" but doesn't when i change the variable with "test" for example... ?

Comment: the option can be selected from a predefined set of words

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought that the right header could be customized.